fit-content doesn't work on ::before element?
::before pseudo-element on a span is wrapping itself.


span {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.float-left {
    display: block;
}

.float-left::before {
    content: "Float: Left --> *Passwords do not match.";
    float: left;
    top: 300px;
}

.whitespace {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.whitespace::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "white-space: nowrap *Passwords do not match.";
    top: 100px;
}

.min-width {
    min-width: fit-content;
}

.min-width::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "min-width --> *Passwords do not match.";
    top: 200px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <span class="whitespace"></span>
    <span class="min-width"></span>
    <span class="float-left"></span>
</body>
</html>



I solved it with white-space: nowrap, but I recently saw a video that mentioned potential overflow issues with this approach. The video suggested an alternative solution, but in my example, min-width: fit-content doesn't seem to work as expected in the video. While tinkering, I discovered that using float: left resolved the issue (though I'm not too familiar with float i wanted to say because for the purpose of the question). Could you explain why it isn't working and share if there is any additional knowledge you have? Thank you for taking your time reading this.

The fit-content keyword is equivalent to fit-content(stretch). In practice, this means that the box will use the available space. Since the pseudo-element has no inherent size it collapses at the first opportunity unless blockified somehow.

Frankly though, that sort of content should not be in a pseudo-element. A pseudo-element is intended for styling purposes not actual content.

span has display: inline by default so the text will wrap when you set min-width: fit-content. note that .float-left has display: block, .whitespace has white-space: nowrap; which will force text to be in one line, but min-width has nothing to make it act as a block, hence it will be inline and the text will wrap.

@MHDAlaaAlhaj i put display:block on float there because the other two span element changes its position because of that. Even if i remove, it is still in a single line. Thank you for your response.

@Paulie_D Thank you for your response. Do you know any insight articles about why elements behave like that? CSS confused me in a lot of ways, and this is one of them.

@FurkanKARADENİZ The problem is because of position: absolute; when you set it and while you don't have content between the opening and closing tag of .min-width, the text coming from pseudo-element hence the width of your element can't be calculated, and is acting like it has width: 0, remove position: absolute; or add width and the text will act like the others.
